# TFS Build Template 2013 Nuget Restore is done before building all solution

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfsbuild

I have noticed that with the TFS Build Template 2013, there's a new activity for doing the nuget restore  before building solutions.

Could someone tell me why this is done before building ALL solutions, instead of being done before building individual solutions ?

The consequences is that the build breaks if a solution publishes its own packages and other solutions (built later in the process) depend on this package.

Answer (score 0):

This is good behavior. I would recommend that you separate the other solution into a separate build. That discrete build then builds and published your NuGet package.  It makes no sense to combine...

Comment: In this case I would have to create multiple builds with builds depending on others. Although I can understand this, I don't find it very practical and I miss the old way, being able to have one single build for every solutions was suitable for my project.